# having issue with receiving data from html to the backend and from backend to another html. Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am receiving ID on click on my main.html page like so:

```
        elements.table.on("rowClick", function(e, row){
            //e - the click event object
            //row - row component
            const ID = row._row.data.ID;
            google.script.run.makeRequest(ID);


        });
```

I am passing this ID to backend function called makeRequest which resides in dataServerSide.gs.

```
function makeRequest(data){
  let newData = data;

  console.log(newData + "this is the first")
  return newData;

}
```

Lastly, I want to pass the data that is in now makeRequest function back to another html called ProjectDetail.html but I am having issues with this. I tried following code snippets.

```
<script>
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((incomingData)=>{
console.log(incomingData)
}).makeRequest(data);
</script>
```

I also tried without passing data argument into makeRequest function like so:

```
<script>
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((incomingData)=>{
console.log(incomingData)
}).makeRequest();
</script>
```

None of them work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Edit: Responding to Tanaike's comment.

Thank you for your help in GAS community Tanaike. I can now use the makeRequest function in ProjectDetails.html by calling it like so:
The incoming data was a string so I used +incomingData to parse it into a number.

```
      function retrieveId(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((incomingData) =>{
        let ID = +incomingData;
        console.log(ID);
      }).makeRequest()
        return ID;
      }
```

And then calling it in pageLoad function like so:

```
      function pageLoad(){
        loadData();
        elements.addNoteBtn = document.getElementById("add-note");
        elements.addNoteBtn.addEventListener("click", addNote)
        retrieveId();
      }
```

I was retrieving the ID data from Main.html like so by saving it into localStorage which is not the best solution.

```
        elements.table.on("rowClick", function(e, row){
            //e - the click event object
            //row - row component
            const ID = row._row.data.ID;
            // google.script.run.makeRequest(ID);

            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((incomingData) => {

            }).makeRequest(ID);



             google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((url) =>{
               // window.open(url,"_self")
               // location.href = url;
               window.top.location = url + "?v=" + ID;
              
             }).getUrl();    

            localStorage.setItem('ID',ID)

        });
```

Now that I receive the ID back from backend, I would like to change the part where I take the ID from localStorage in ProjectDetails.html:

```
<script>
      let ID = localStorage.getItem("ID");
</script>
```

I tried this in ProjectDetails.html to set the ID to the returned ID from makeRequest function but it says that ID cannot be used before initialization.

```
let ID = retrieveId();

      function retrieveId(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((incomingData) =>{
        let ID = +incomingData;
        console.log(ID);
      }).makeRequest()
        return ID;
      }



      const elements = {};
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", pageLoad)
      

      function pageLoad(){
        loadData();
        elements.addNoteBtn = document.getElementById("add-note");
        elements.addNoteBtn.addEventListener("click", addNote)
        retrieveId();
      }
```

This is later used in html with Tabulator like so:

```
function loadData(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((projectDetailsData) =>{
        const table = new Tabulator("#project-details0", {
        dataTree:true,
        height:"100%", // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
        data: projectDetailsData, //assign data to table
        layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        movableColumns:true,
        columns:[ //Define Table Columns
          {title:"ID", field:"ID"},
          {title:"Project Name", field:"Project Name"},
          {title:"Status", field:"Status", editor:"list", editorParams:{values:["Postponed", "In use", "Archieved", "In Development"]}},
          {title:"Change Date", field:"Change Date"},
          {title:"Priority", field:"Priority"},
          {title:"Owner", field:"Owner"},
        ],
      });


      }).withFailureHandler((error) =>{

        alert(error)
      }).findProjectDetailsById(ID,0,6)}
```

findProjectDetailsById(id) is run in the backend in DataServerSide.gs like so:

```
function findProjectDetailsById(id) {
  let data = getDataBySheet(PROJECT_SHEET_NAME);
  let headers = data.shift();
  let jsData = data.map(row => transformRow(headers, row));

  let projectDetails = jsData.find(row => row.ID == id);

  if (projectDetails) {
    let projectArray = [{}]; // Initialize an array with an empty object
    headers.forEach(header => {
      projectArray[0][header] = projectDetails[header];
    });
    return projectArray;
  } else {
    return null; // Return null if project with given ID is not found
  }
}
```

I know this is a lot of question but I asked my colleagues, unfortunately they are super busy and I am new when it comes to web application in GAS. if I can use this ID correctly in new html, I can finally progress with the project. Thank you again for your time. I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, I guessed that you might have wanted to keep the value from the function `makeRequest`. In this case, how about using PropertiesService? When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification? In this modification, your function `makeRequest` on the Google Apps Script side is modified.

#### Modified script:

```js
function makeRequest(data) {
  const p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  let newData;
  if (data) {
    p.setProperty("data", data);
    newData = data;
  } else {
    const data = p.getProperty("data") || "";
    newData = data;
  }

  console.log(newData + "this is the first")
  return newData;
}
```

- By this modification, when `google.script.run.makeRequest(ID)` is run on the Javascript side, `ID` is stored in the Properties service.
- And, when `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((incomingData)=>{console.log(incomingData)}).makeRequest()` is run, the stored value is loaded and returns the value.
- In this case, from your showing script, I guessed that only one value might be stored. So, I proposed the above script. If you want to select the stored value, you can achieve this using the keys as follows.

  ```js
  function makeRequest(key, data) {
    const p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    let newData;
    if (data) {
      p.setProperty(key, data);
      newData = data;
    } else {
      const data = p.getProperty(key) || "";
      newData = data;
    }
    console.log(newData + "this is the first")
    return newData;
  }
  ```

  - In this case, when `google.script.run.makeRequest("key1", ID)` is run on the Javascript side, `ID` is stored in the Properties service.
  - And, when `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((incomingData)=>{console.log(incomingData)}).makeRequest("key1")` is run, the stored value is loaded and returns the value.

#### Reference:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

Comment: Hello Tanaike, I marked this as correct answer, thank you very much. Could you also please help with my edited question? Thank you again.

Comment: @Sloth99 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Could you also please help with my edited question?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your new question. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your new question, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions soon.